# Why “desert” in the following examples are used as uncountable?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammaticality, uncountable-nouns

Below are some dictionary examples in which the noun *desert* is used as an uncountable:

> this area of the country is mostly desert (Longman)
>
> drought and deforestation are turning fragile grasslands into desert (Oxford)

*desert* in the sense of *a particular arid area* is countable. I am wondering why it is uncountable in the examples aforequoted. Is there any subtle change in meaning when it is used as uncountable?

Answer (score 6):

Topographical features are expressed that way quite often.

> There was about fifteen feet of beach from the near end of the pier to the waterline.
>
> The land around the cabin was mostly forest, with a few outcroppings of rock.
>
> If you drive through Iowa it's cornfield as far as you can see.

In all of these cases the feature in question is not being used as a discrete entity but as a descriptor for the *type* of land being talked about. There are other ways to say those things — "the beach", "forested", "cornfields" — but then there are different ways to say almost anything. The usages above, and your example as well, are common and unexceptional.